# How to display the session 'username' value of the logged-in User using the 'codeigniter4/shield' framework for CodeIgniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm new to CodeIgniter and I installed the [`codeigniter4/shield`](https://packagist.org/packages/codeigniter4/shield) authentication and authorization framework for CodeIgniter 4.

I need the session data of the logged-in User such as `username`, and `email`.

How can I get it?

What I've tried so far.

```php
$item = $session->get('item');
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Solution:

Get logged-in [username](https://github.com/codeigniter4/shield/blob/697f570277a4d2205852cacaae4837604b1c4b88/src/Entities/User.php#L22):

```php
auth()->user()->username;
```

Get logged-in [User email](https://github.com/codeigniter4/shield/blob/697f570277a4d2205852cacaae4837604b1c4b88/src/Entities/User.php#L213):

```php
auth()->user()->getEmail();
```

Get the ['date & time'](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/ea1b62872329076616287a20b879efb628c35d1a/system/I18n/TimeTrait.php#L850) when the logged-in User account was created:

```php
auth()->user()->created_at->toDateTimeString();
```

Get all logged-in [User data](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/ea1b62872329076616287a20b879efb628c35d1a/system/Entity/Entity.php#L197).

```php
auth()->user()->toRawArray();
```

##### Reference:

[Auth Helper](https://codeigniter4.github.io/shield/authentication/#auth-helper)

> The auth functionality is designed to be used with the `auth_helper`
> that comes with Shield. This helper method provides the `auth()`
> command which returns a convenient interface to the most frequently
> used functionality within the auth libraries. This must be loaded
> before it can be used.
>
> ```php
> // get the current user
> auth()->user();
>
> // get the current user's id
> auth()->id();
> // or
> user_id();
> ```

Comment: I've been struggling for 2 days and I didn't expect it to be that simple. Thanks.